# How can I modify HTML code generated by 'Wordpress Editor' in ADD NEW POST?

Tags: wordpress, editor, customization

I need to modify the html code generated by wp-editor (TinyMice, WYSIWIG etc) According to my requirements.

[image]

Let say if I press `Add Media` button. I want to modify code generated by editor.
For example editor generates the following:

```
<img src="abc.png"/>
```

and I want the following code.

```
<div style="background-image: url('abc.png')> </div>
```

And similarly for other buttons.

I am looking towards a solution at `insertion time` instead of manipulating all the post at `DB level`.

I hope there must be some solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On your post edit you see two tabs. Visual and Text. Click on Text Tab and you will see HTML generated.

See below image and click on "Text" tab.

[image]

Comment: No brother. Thats autogenerated code. in `Text tab` I want to modify that code from WP as dynamic conversion.